# How are community promotion ads counted?

Tags: support, advertising, open-source-advertising

I was checking the community promotion ad stats at [Physics meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2810). I found that each click of mine counts in the `Total clicks`. I thought the total clicks is based on each IP address. But, it's not.

I clicked 4 or 5 times from my computer and the total clicks (plus, the ratio) has increased by that amount. If I alone (a single IP) can increase the count, what's the use of it then?

Comment: Did you want to post this as a [meta-tag:bug]?

Comment: @AsheeshR: If you think that's a bug, go on. Retag it. Well, I don't know whether it's done on purpose or accidental. That's why I just posted it as support ;-)